# Why do I get 4 bytes for a char in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct

```
file1 = open("test.txt", 'wb')
file1.write(struct.pack('icic', 1, '\t', 2, '\n'))
file1.close()
print os.path.getsize("test.txt")
```

It gives me 13. But I think it should be 4 + 1 + 4 + 1 = 10 bytes. It seems that it stores '\n' for one byte, but '\t' for 4 bytes. And idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just have a look at `struct.pack('icic', 1, '\t', 2, '\n')` itself?

Comment: You mean the source code?

Comment: No, I mean the result of the function call. On my machine, this gives `'\x01\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\n'` which means 4 bytes (little endian) for the 1, 4 bytes for the `\t`, 4 bytes (LE) for the 2 and one byte for the `\n`. And this, in turn means, three 0-bytes are inserted after the `\t`. If you have a look at this, you get some steps further.

Comment: BTW, you should have your file formats portable, so that you can easily share them between machines of different architecture. For this, you should use the `>` prefix. In this case, you have the byte order you wand, and you get no fill bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the actual struct size, use [`struct.calcsize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.calcsize('icic')
13
```

That's because you are using the default alignment, and then C rules are applied:

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned **by skipping pad bytes if necessary** (according to the rules used by the C compiler).

The first `ic` would be just 5 bytes, but C would pad that out to 8 if you list it twice, so the next `ic` pair brings it to 13. If you used 3 `ic` pairs you'd get to 21, etc. C pads out the `i` integers to align to 4-byte groups. This [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is used to improve memory performance, but can be unexpected when trying to use it for different purposes.

Pick an explicit byte order instead:

```
>>> struct.calcsize('>icic')
10
```

See the [*Byte Order, Size and Alignment* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought it is because of padding.